# fabric API direct call in python

Tags: python, fabric

i remember fabric API can be called directly in py script
but forgot where to start
anybody give a clue?

Comment: What do you mean? Call a `fab` file from another python file during the latter's execution?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, you can call it, for example:

```
from fabric.api import run
from fabric.tasks import execute


def do_something():
    run("echo $RANDOM")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    execute(do_something, hosts=["username@host"])
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a whole section on using fabric [as a library](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/library.html) in the docs. I'd refer to that and how best to approach fabric's use in this way.

Specifically, you'll want to address the problem of performing task `X` on a list of hosts `Y` by using the execute function as `execute( X, hosts=Y )`. When you are done, you should disconnect from all of the connected hosts. Normally the `fab` tool does this for you, but you must do this manually when using fabric as a library. Fabric 0.9.4 and later have a `disconnect_all()` function. Ideally, this should be in the `finally` clause of a `try...finally` statement.

Comment: me not sure I understand this: `how best to approach it use`

Comment: hopefully clarified. But mostly just read that docs link, and you'll know how to use fabric how you're attempting.

Comment: still not clear to me what you mean... what is *this* in `in this way`

Comment: as a library. the way you want to use it. w/o calling fab. etc