# How does one automate the install of lessc using pip and setup.py?

Tags: python, django, less, setup.py

I have a django project that uses the django-static-precompiler, which required `lessc` (a css pre-processor) for converting LESS files into CSS.

Unfortunately, `lessc` is not a Python program, and the django-static-precompiler documentation doesn't give tips on how to include this automatically.

I'd like a user to be able to run `setup.py install` and be at a point where the system is relatively functional, but this is a small hurdle.

What can I put in setup.py to require the install of `lessc`, or any non-pip available package for that matter?

Comment: Did you check out fabric and fabtools? They can install system packages for you or run any other system command. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861802/fabric-api-direct-call-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Try the [virtual-less](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtual-less) package.  It uses [python-less](https://github.com/linssen/python-less) to create a `lessc` executable in your virtualenv.

```
pip install virtual-lessc

lessc styles.scss styles.css
```

Comment: it's got to be 'pip install virtual-less'